# Selecting images by ratio in css

Tags: css, image, css-selectors, less

I want to apply a class on image elements, but only for those which got a landscape format.

So, I want to know if there is a way to select images on my html, having a width/height ratio greater than 1, just like the media queries do with the "device-pixel-ratio" filter.

I actually do this in Javascript, but this can be better to do it in css (or with css framework like less/stylus/sass etc..)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Media queries inspect the user's screen properties, which is why it can select for screen width and even retina displays. To read the properties of the images themselves would not be possible in LESS or CSS.

LESS and its compiler, whether client-side or server side will just compile to CSS so there's nothing inherent in LESS that will read your HTML, let alone images.

CSS would get you closer, but reads your HTML semantically, not looking at the inner properties of media elements like images or video.

Comment: I think the same. I only had hoped that there is a native way in CSS to do this... but it doesn't look to exist